# HTML aggility pack wont return div ids from web site

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using Google as an example to test and I know that there are divs with ids on the page

If I use xpath "//div"  it returns 14 divs in my collection with no id text

If I use xpath "//div/@id"  it returns 0 divs

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks code is below

```
Dim l As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim w As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
Dim h As HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://www.google.com/")

Dim ht As HtmlNodeCollection = h.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id")


For Each x As HtmlNode In ht

    l.Add(x.Id)

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression selects a collection of `id` *attributes* rather than a collection of `div` *elements*. Change it to this: `//div[@id]`